# How can I have an R code to wait background R sessions to finish?

Tags: r, command-line

I have used the command line to run multiple R sessions without wait=False
such as system(paste0("Rscript Example.R"),start," ",end),wait=FALSE)

Basically, it runs the for loop chunks in parallel, which is great and very fast.

So my question is, how can I have another R code to waiting for all of these runs to finish and then start? I will combine the outputs of these sessions.

thanks in advance

system(paste0("Rscript Example.R"),start," ",end),wait=FALSE)

Comment: What you're doing feels counter-R as you're calling Rscript from R. Why not to `source`  Rscript and use it's functions in parallel loop? I suppose this is how this are usually done.

Comment: Actually, I couldn't get enough performance with R parallel packages. Maybe I couldn't use it correctly. This method was much faster and easy to manage for me. If there is no way to do this, I might go back to R parallel packages

Comment: You can make `Example.R` to create some file in the end and there could be a `while` loop running in the main process and checking if all expected files are generated.

Comment: Makes sense. I have something similar to that. I was thinking if there is any specific ID to track the status of the background task. Because one caveat of the while loop is, if there is an error it will wait forever. (or there will be some time limit etc. but not great)